# How can I change the color of an svg Icon inside embed code?

Tags: html, css

I inserted an embed booking widget into my website - it works fine, but the color of the icons in the widget is white, therefore they are invisible on my page.

I'm looking for a way to give the icons a different color, so they are visible on my page. The icons are SVGs

This is the actual embed code. (I've removed the URL and website id, but am happy to provide it, if needed)

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="" src="https://cdn.lodgify.com/portable-search-bar/1.43.3/renderPortableSearchBar.js"></script><div><div id="lodgify-search-bar" data-website-id="123456" data-language-code="de" data-checkout-page-url="URL" data-dates-check-in-label="Anreise" data-dates-check-out-label="Abreise" data-guests-counter-label="Gast" data-guests-input-singular-label="{{NumberOfGuests}} gast" data-guests-input-plural-label="{{NumberOfGuests}} gäste" data-location-input-label="Ort" data-search-button-label="Suche" data-new-tab="true">
 </div>
 <style type="text/css">
 html {
   --lodgify-ui-action-color: #606765;
   --lodgify-ui-action-darker-color: #4d5251;
   --lodgify-ui-action-lighter-color: #bfc2c1;
   --lodgify-ui-action-contrast-color: #ffffff;
 }
 </style>
 </div>
```

when inspecting the icon elements this is what i get `#lodgify-search-bar i.icon`

I'm an absolute noob and any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: it depends if your embeds are yours or not, how they are written and their dependencies, if they are in a sandbox...etc. your question is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

Set the fill color for the class that selects the icon. So something like this (to change the fill color to red:

```
#lodgify-search-bar i.icon {
    fill:#ff0000;
}
```

The above assumes the icon svgs will support this.